# I can speak a little bit of German

Tags: grammaticality, measuring-units

I was asked to introduce myself and what languages I spoke. So I mentioned all the languages I know and in the end, I added "***... and I can speak a little bit of German***"

After I said that, I was wondering if I used the correct expression. Should it have been:

1. I can speak some German
2. I can speak a little German
3. I can speak a little bit German
4. I can speak a little bit of German
5. All 1-4
6. None of 1-4

Please provide your comments.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You may be interested in our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but the short answer is that all are fine except #3, where *German* would probably be interpreted as an adverbial usage.

Comment: As others have said, all but #3 work. Interestingly enough, *in German* you would say "Ich spreche ein bisschen Deutsche," which translates to "I speak a little German." (Well, I think it is interesting, at least.)

Comment: @MrsLannister, you made a good point connecting the German translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of 1,2 or 4, I would say; but they imply a subtly different amount of knowledge, with 1 being the most and 4 the least.

The form in 3 feels ungrammatical, though I think it might be used in some dialects.

Comment: (3) means that you can assume a slight German accent.

Comment: Good point, @Andrew. :-)

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. Asking the question was the easy part. Selecting the right answer is tough.

Answer (score 1):

All of them but three are grammatically correct; I think preference probably stems from the dialect of the speaker. Four is more common in the SE US.